# Extracting title from link in Python (Beautiful soup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python and I'm looking to extract the title from a link. So far I have the following but have hit a dead end:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("http://books.toscrape.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
books = soup.find("section")
book_list = books.find_all(class_="product_pod")
tonight = book_list[0]

for book in book_list:
    price = book.find(class_="price_color").get_text()
    title = book.find('a')
    print (price)
    print (title.contents[0])
```

Comment: you want to get <title> content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("http://books.toscrape.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
books = soup.find("section")
book_list = books.find_all(class_="product_pod")
tonight = book_list[0]

for book in book_list:
    price = book.find(class_="price_color").get_text()
    title = book.select_one('a img')['alt']
    print (title)
```

Output:

```
A Light in the Attic
Tipping the Velvet
Soumission
Sharp Objects
Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind
The Requiem Red...
```

Comment: This is not giving title of anchor.

Comment: fixed, please try it

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

To extract title from links, you can use `title` attribute.

Fore example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("http://books.toscrape.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('h3 > a'):
    print(a['title'])
```

Prints:

```
A Light in the Attic
Tipping the Velvet
Soumission
Sharp Objects
Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind
The Requiem Red
The Dirty Little Secrets of Getting Your Dream Job
The Coming Woman: A Novel Based on the Life of the Infamous Feminist, Victoria Woodhull
The Boys in the Boat: Nine Americans and Their Epic Quest for Gold at the 1936 Berlin Olympics
The Black Maria
Starving Hearts (Triangular Trade Trilogy, #1)
Shakespeare's Sonnets
Set Me Free
Scott Pilgrim's Precious Little Life (Scott Pilgrim #1)
Rip it Up and Start Again
Our Band Could Be Your Life: Scenes from the American Indie Underground, 1981-1991
Olio
Mesaerion: The Best Science Fiction Stories 1800-1849
Libertarianism for Beginners
It's Only the Himalayas
```

Answer (score 1):

By just modifying your existing code you can use the alt text which contains the book titles in your example.

```
print (title.contents[0].attrs["alt"])
```